# electricity is out in half the side of the house

Tags: electrical

The garage power is out so I can't use my washer due to no power but the dryer comes on because different plug. The bathroom light and front room light won't work and outlets won't work in living room. It's wierd cause the three bedrooms work fine but it's more of the front house that doesn't work. 
Smud came out and trimmed trees and repaired a line but said to fix the inside wiring ourselves. Landlord hasn't fixed for over five months after informing them of the issue. 
When I flip the breaker on and off the washer comes on for second then stops.  But the lights don't come on or flicker.

Comment: Is your dryer electric or gas?

Comment: Also, what make and model is your electrical panel?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, you should look into tenant rights in your region, where I come from, this is something a landlord must attend to, and you may have financial/legal recourse.

Comment: Go to the circuit breaker panel.  For each breaker, figure out what it powers -- often listed on the panel -- and whether the things on that breaker have lost power.  If everything on that breaker has lost power, put a sticker on it. (don't particularly care what kind).  Do this for each breaker.   If any device powered by the breaker works, no sticker.   Then shoot  a photo of the panel and post it here.  That will tell us a LOT.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like one of the legs coming into the house isnt working correctly. if you look at the breakers, I'm willing to bet that all the ones that are not working are all on the same side of the panel. If its an older home there could be a fuse somewhere on that line that blew from the tree trimmers and having the line repaired. OR i would have the utility company come out again and look at it, make sure that both lines going into the house are working correctly, to at least eliminate any outside issues. If the utility company still says everything is working on their end, then I'd be looking inside the panel/s to see if there is a fuse.

Comment: Would that explain the washer starting briefly when the breaker is flipped?

Comment: @Mark I hear what you're trying to say, but poles don't work that way, except in Pushmatic panels.  Normally a pole is on every other [*row* of breakers.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you can make something on the dead circuit come on briefly by flipping the breaker but it dies again quickly, then there is probably a short that is tripping the breaker. You could try looking for damaged wiring  (did a tree fall on something?) or unplugging everything (in case there's a busted appliance that's shorting and tripping the breaker). Your landlord really should fix this immediately as wiring problems can be a fire hazard.